# Windows Server Backup: list backups on destination

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, powershell, windows-server-backup

I need to retrieve the list of backups on a system's backup volume via script. The information I am after can be found in the WSB GUI after clicking "View details" of the *"Destination usage"* part in the *"Scheduled Backup"* section:

[image: details of backups]

I know about the [*Get-WBBackupSet*](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ee706675.aspx) cmdlet, but this is only the list of backups WB knows it has done in the past, not necessarily what is present on the backup destination, which seems to be re-read dynamically each time I click "Refresh information":

[image: Destination usage]

How is Windows Server Backup gathering the destination information?

Rationale: I would like to set up monitoring for the backup runs performed by WB to make sure a sufficiently deep backup history is present. The list of backup sets returned by `Get-WBBackupSet` seems not always consistent with what's on disk, so I rather would not rely on this information for the monitoring check.

Comment: wabbit the result is not the same!! Get-WBBackupSet return entire catalog while wssadmin return only online shadow.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have WS2008R2 machine right away, but this is what I get on WS2012R2,

if issuing the command: `wbadmin get versions`

[image: wbadmin get versions]

**UPD:** If you run the command like: `wbadmin get items -version:10/03/2015-16:01`

You will get the following:

[image]

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: `wbadmin get versions` seems to return the same list as `Get-WBBackupSet`, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

With the command "wssadmin list shadows" you get the list of shadow copies.
Now we can put the list in the PowerShell variable "$copy online"

```
$copyonline = vssadmin list shadows
```

So we have to only filter the results and count items.

```
($copyonline -like "*shadow Copy Volume*").count
```

The number is the copies available.

Comment: This answer needs more explanation.